# Selecting charts without referencing the chart number

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to select a random chart on a sheet in excel using VBA without knowing the chart number because the chart generated always changes in number. Could anyone help please? Is it possible to select a chart without referencing the chart number? I want to change the chart name of the active chart.

```
1   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 409").Activate
2   ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 409").Name = "Chart 1"
3   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
```

Comment: Instead of calling chart by name you need to call it by index: `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate` for 1st one in `Activesheet`. Changing 1 to random number will give you random reference.

Comment: If you want active chart, use `Selection.Name="..."`

Comment: Thanks KazJaw and LS_dev. The reason I need this is because my chart always updates , its name changes and hence I cannot have a fix reference name. However, ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate work just fine and it randomly selects. Thanks so much! What a relief.

Comment: @KazJaw: Write up an answer...

Answer (score 1):

To select all the charts or the Random one, You can use chart Index.

```
Sub getcharts()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ch As ChartObject
Set ws = ActiveSheet

cnt = ws.ChartObjects.Count
random_num = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, cnt)

ws.ChartObjects(random_num).Name = "NAM"  'The Random chart
For Each ch In ws.ChartObjects
    ch.Name = "Put the name of Chart here "
    'Or Do anything with you all the charts here
Next


End Sub
```